# Save pandas correlation matrix instead of displaying it

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to save the pandas correlation matrix instead of displaying it. 
Here is the code I have tried. This code displays image and saves it. I just want to save the correlation plot, but don't want to display it.

```
for subject in range(len(train)):
  for trial in range(subject):
    df = pd.DataFrame(train[subject][trial], columns=channels)
    img=plt.matshow(df.corr())
    plt.savefig('train_images/result_{}_{}.png'.format(subject,trial), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have this code in a Jupyter notebook, with `%matplotlib inline`. Then you can just put

```
plt.close()
```

after `plt.savefig(...)` to prevent the figure from being embedded in the notebook.